# Port forwarding on debian before setting tor exit relay live required?

Tags: exit-relays, debian

Before setting exit relay live, do I have to setup port forwarding for 9001, as ORPort is using it if so then how I will do it on Debian Stretch 9.0.

```
*Torrc file below;*<br>

ORPort 9001<br>
DirPort 80<br>
Nickname Name<br>
RelayBandwidthRate 1024 KB<br>
RelayBandwidthBurst 1024 KB<br>
ContactInfo Name <Email>
```

```
DirPortFrontPage  /./usr/share/doc/tor/tor-exit-notice.html<br><br>
ExitPolicy accept *:20-23     # FTP, SSH, telnet<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:43        # WHOIS<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:53        # DNS<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:79-81     # finger, HTTP<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:88        # kerberos<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:110       # POP3<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:143       # IMAP<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:194       # IRC<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:220       # IMAP3<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:389       # LDAP<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:443       # HTTPS<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:464       # kpasswd<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:531       # IRC/AIM<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:543-544   # Kerberos<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:554       # RTSP<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:563       # NNTP over SSL<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:636       # LDAP over SSL<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:706       # SILC<br>
ExitPolicy accept *:749       # kerberos 
ExitPolicy accept *:873       # rsync
ExitPolicy accept *:902-904   # VMware
ExitPolicy accept *:981       # Remote HTTPS management for firewall
ExitPolicy accept *:989-995   # FTP over SSL, telnets, IMAP over SSL, etc
ExitPolicy accept *:1194      # OpenVPN
ExitPolicy accept *:1220      # QT Server Admin
ExitPolicy accept *:1293      # PKT-KRB-IPSec
ExitPolicy accept *:1500      # VLSI License Manager
ExitPolicy accept *:1533      # Sametime
ExitPolicy accept *:1677      # GroupWise
ExitPolicy accept *:1723      # PPTP
ExitPolicy accept *:1755      # RTSP
ExitPolicy accept *:1863      # MSNP
ExitPolicy accept *:2082      # Infowave Mobility Server
ExitPolicy accept *:2083      # Secure Radius Service (radsec)
ExitPolicy accept *:2086-2087 # GNUnet, ELI
ExitPolicy accept *:2095-2096 # NBX
ExitPolicy accept *:2102-2104 # Zephyr
ExitPolicy accept *:3128      # SQUID
ExitPolicy accept *:3389      # MS WBT
ExitPolicy accept *:3690      # SVN
ExitPolicy accept *:4321      # RWHOIS
ExitPolicy accept *:4643      # Virtuozzo
ExitPolicy accept *:5050      # MMCC
ExitPolicy accept *:5190      # ICQ
ExitPolicy accept *:5222-5223 # XMPP, XMPP over SSL
ExitPolicy accept *:5228      # Android Market
ExitPolicy accept *:5900      # VNC
ExitPolicy accept *:6660-6669 # IRC
ExitPolicy accept *:6679      # IRC SSL  
ExitPolicy accept *:6697      # IRC SSL  
ExitPolicy accept *:8000      # iRDMI
ExitPolicy accept *:8008      # HTTP alternate
ExitPolicy accept *:8074      # Gadu-Gadu
ExitPolicy accept *:8080      # HTTP Proxies
ExitPolicy accept *:8087-8088 # Simplify Media SPP Protocol, Radan HTTP
ExitPolicy accept *:8332-8333 # BitCoin
ExitPolicy accept *:8443      # PCsync HTTPS
ExitPolicy accept *:8888      # HTTP Proxies, NewsEDGE
ExitPolicy accept *:9418      # git
ExitPolicy accept *:9999      # distinct
ExitPolicy accept *:10000     # Network Data Management Protocol
ExitPolicy accept *:11371     # OpenPGP hkp (http keyserver protocol)
ExitPolicy accept *:12350     # Skype
ExitPolicy accept *:19294     # Google Voice TCP
ExitPolicy accept *:19638     # Ensim control panel
ExitPolicy accept *:23456     # Skype
ExitPolicy accept *:33033     # Skype
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

```
% cat ~/.tor/torrc
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have public IP address you do not need setup forwarding for ORport. I have better experience with running on port 443, it is less likely blocked by corporate proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is! You have to have it prepared beforehand, so the self-test and a reach-ability test will be firing up positive at startup